# Logstash-input-mongodb configuration file

Tags: mongodb, elasticsearch, logstash

I am trying to pull data from a mongoDB to Elasticsearch using logstash.
I am using the  Logstash-input-mongodb plugin. This is my config file:

```
input {
    mongodb {
        uri => 'mongodb://localhost:27017/test'
        placeholder_db_dir => '/opt/logstash-mongodb/'
        placeholder_db_name => 'logstash_sqlite.db'
        collection => 'student'
        batch_size => 202
    }
}

filter {

}

output {
    elasticsearch {
        host => "localhost:9200"
        user => elastic
        password => changeme
        index => "testStudent"
    }
    stdout { codec => rubydebug }
}
```

I am having an error saying:

> Pipelines YAML file is empty.

Is this because I left the filter part empty?

Comment: i am also getting the same error. Does logstash-input-mongodb happens?